# Scraping Sony camera webpage cant access Specification tab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

URL = https://electronics.sony.com/imaging/interchangeable-lens-cameras/full-frame/p/ilce7rm4-b

I need to scrape specifications tab from each camera. It loads after first tapping specification and then see more How to load this data with selenium python script.

I tried

```
def specs_see_more(driver):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                        '//*[@id="PDPSpecificationsLink"]')))
    time.sleep(3)
    see_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                    '//*[@id="PDPSpecificationsLink"]')))

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", see_more_button)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of(see_more_button))

    see_more_button.click()

    spec_page_source = driver.page_source
    driver_soup = BeautifulSoup(spec_page_source, "html.parser")
    print(driver_soup)
```

This first clicking specification button and then opening see more but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
see_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                    '//*[@id="PDPSpecificationsLink"]')))
```

In the above line of code, XPATH expression to locate <kbd>See More</kbd> button is incorrect.

Refer the following working code to click on <kbd>See More</kbd> button within "Specification" tab:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://electronics.sony.com/imaging/interchangeable-lens-cameras/full-frame/p/ilce7rm4-b")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Below line will click on 'Specifications' tab
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "PDPSpecificationsLink"))).click()
# Below line will click on 'See More' button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[contains(text(),'See More')])[2]"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: But sometimes it returns this error 
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found

Comment: `StaleElementReferenceException` - This exception can occur when the web element which your script is interacting with has changed. I suggest raising a new question to this particular issue, make sure you include all the reproducible details, like relevant code etc. This way you will get answers from wider audience.

Comment: Okay thanks Shawn will do.